# Flexbox behaviour goes against its philosophy

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm new to this topic and read myself into it. I worked through [this](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) guide.

In this guide they say:

`The main idea behind the flex layout is to give the container the ability to alter its items' width/height (and order) to best fill the available space.`

I want Flexbox to use all available space, but obviously right under 2 there is empty space and also enough space for the element 3.
When I take a look at the philosophy of Flexbox I can see not used but available space in my layout.

Am I doing something wrong in my css or is Flexbox broken?

*Layout/Output*
[image: Custom layout]

*CSS*

```
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;

  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;

  align-items: flex-start;

  -webkit-flex-flow: wrap;
}

.flex-item {
  background: tomato;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 300px;
  margin-top: 10px;

  line-height: 150px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

*HTML*

```
<ul class="flex-container">
  <li class="flex-item">1111111111 1111111111</li>
  <li class="flex-item">2</li>
  <li class="flex-item">3</li>
  <li class="flex-item">4</li>
  <li class="flex-item">5</li>
  <li class="flex-item">6</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: For some grid ideas, you can get creative with `vw` and `vh` lengths and plenty of `calc()`. [You can get some pretty neat fluid layouts](http://jsfiddle.net/w35cys7f/). I still haven't wrapped my head around flexbox completely though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flexbox is primarily a one-dimensional layout mode. It lets you distribute & size elements responsively, in just a single axis (horizontal *or* vertical), and then it supports basic alignment/stretching in the other axis.

`flex-wrap: wrap` can make it *look* two-dimensional, but really it just lets you split your flex items into "lines", where each "line" is like a one-dimension flexbox. And the lines don't overlap (or really interact at all).

So, in your diagram, the "3" element doesn't fill in the empty space because it's in a separate flex line from where the empty space is, and the flex lines cannot overlap.

To achieve what you want in pure CSS, I think you'll need [CSS Grid](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-grid/), specifically with [`grid-auto-flow: dense`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-grid/#valdef-grid-auto-flow-auto-flow-algorithm-dense). This spec is still under active development, though, and browsers have mixed levels of implementation, so it's not ready for use in production websites yet.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your CSS is slighty wrong

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/w860ku81/1/)

**CSS**

```
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;

  flex-wrap: wrap; /* here */
}

.flex-item {

  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;

  background: tomato;
  padding: 5px;
  width:300px;
  margin-top: 10px;

  line-height: 150px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

**However**, on further discussion it appears that what you are trying to achieve is not possible (AFAIK) with `flexbox`.

> I expect element 3 to move under 2, so all the empty space is used

Accordingly, I think a JS solution like [**Masonry.Js**](http://masonry.desandro.com/) would be the recommended solution.

Comment: When I add `align-items: flex-start;` I still have the same problem.

Comment: Why do you need `flex-start`?

Comment: I don't want the element to be bigger than it has to be. Basically I create space adding this line.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: I expect element 3 to move under 2, so all the empty space is used.

Comment: Ah...flexbox can't do that..at least as far as I know. You're effectively switching 'columns' & 'rows' in mid-stream. Of course, there may be an esoteric method but that sort of arrangement is normally left to Javascript like http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: Would you add this to your answer, so I can mark it as helpful?